# How to check whether a file is_open and the open_status in python

Tags: python

Is there any python functions such as:

```
filename = "a.txt"
if is_open(filename) and open_status(filename)=='w':
   print filename," is open for writing"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not quite what you want, since it just tests whether a given file is write-able. But in case it's helpful:

```
import os

filename = "a.txt"
if not os.access(filename, os.W_OK):
    print "Write access not permitted on %s" % filename
```

(I'm not aware of any platform-independent way to do what you ask)

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that os.access only checks the readability/writability of a file, but I want to check whether the file has ALREADY been opened or not. Thanks for further suggestions.

Comment: You may be technically correct, but it sure isn't helpful to have this as the first result when searching for how to test filehandle status.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an is_open solution for windows using ctypes:

```
from ctypes import cdll

_sopen = cdll.msvcrt._sopen
_close = cdll.msvcrt._close
_SH_DENYRW = 0x10

def is_open(filename):
    if not os.access(filename, os.F_OK):
        return False # file doesn't exist
    h = _sopen(filename, 0, _SH_DENYRW, 0)
    if h == 3:
        _close(h)
        return False # file is not opened by anyone else
    return True # file is already open
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do that is to try.

```
def is_already_opened_in_write_mode(filename)
     if os.path.exists(filename):
         try:
             f = open(filename, 'a')
             f.close()
         except IOError:
             return True
     return False
```

Comment: ⚠ DANGER − Calling `open(filename, 'w')` will delete the contents of the file.  A *slightly* better solution would be to call `open(filename, 'a')`.  Better yet, don't open the file at all, and use the API function for checking if a file is writable.

Comment: If I recall correctly thé question was to detect if à file was opened by another program not if it is writable (hence just cheking access)

Answer (score 1):

There is a attribute to check the open status or mode of a file.

```
filename = open('open.txt','r')
print(filename.mode)
```

Python has an inbuilt attribute called 'mode'. Above code will return 'r'.
Similarly if you open a file in 'w' mode above code will return 'w'

You can also check if a file is open or closed

```
print(filename.closed)
```

This will return 'FALSE' as the file is in open state.

```
filename.closed
print(filename.closed)
```

This will return 'TRUE' because the file is now in close state.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is an easy way to do what you want, but a start could be to redefine open() and add your own managing code. That said, why do you want to do that?

Comment: This would only help, if the responsible code were also in Python and under control of the developer.