# How to check if a file is R/W locked

Tags: python, file-io, unicode, msvcrt

I already checked out [Python : Check file is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371444/python-check-file-is-locked) and [How to check whether a file is_open and the open_status in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231719/how-to-check-whether-a-file-is-open-and-the-open-status-in-python).
Generally, the following code suits my need, but it doesn't work in Python 2 for Unicode strings.

```
from ctypes import cdll

_sopen = cdll.msvcrt._sopen
_close = cdll.msvcrt._close
_SH_DENYRW = 0x10

def is_open(filename):
    h = _sopen(filename, 0, _SH_DENYRW, 0)
    try:
     return h == -1
    finally:
        _close(h)
```

Any suggestions what I should do?

Comment: files encoded in unicode, or the filename itself is a unicode string?

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: type(filename).
It wouldn't matter what the file's encoding is.

Comment: Look at what `*A()` ("ANSI") win32 API function is called by `_sopen` and call the corresponding `*W` (wide) function for Unicode strings.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved!
Just needed to add a two lines:

```
from ctypes import cdll

_sopen = cdll.msvcrt._sopen
_wsopen = cdll.msvcrt._wsopen
_close = cdll.msvcrt._close
_SH_DENYRW = 0x10

def is_open(filename):
    func = _wsopen if type(filename) is unicode else _sopen
    h = func(filename, 0, _SH_DENYRW, 0)
    try:
     return h == -1
    finally:
        _close(h)
```

Comment: there is no reason to reject unicode subclasses: use `isinstance(filename, unicode)` instead of `type(filename) is unicode` (also, I'm not sure it is guaranteed that there is only one `unicode` class instance i.e., you might need `==` instead of `is` here).